# Submarine with inside furnishing?

Tags: modeling

Is it possible to create an object so that a person could sit inside and see the equipment inside of the submarine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is.

Just create furnishing and equipment, position it inside the submarine, and then put the camera there.